# New session id regenerated after ajax call in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, session

I develop following js in my view.

```
var url       = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit/';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ajax-loader").hide();
    $("#personaldetails-en-di-icon").click(function(){
        $("#ajax-loader").show();
        $.post(url+'ajax/personaldetails/enable', {}, function(data){
            console.log(data);  
        });
     });
});
```

so,when I click ,it request edit controller.

in edit controller I have 
    private $id = null;

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('input');
    $this->load->model('editcv_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->id = $this->session->userdata('login');        
    if (intval($this->id) < 1)
        die(json_encode(array('response' => 'not logged in')));
    }

    public function _remap($method = '',$param = array()){
        echo (json_encode(array('response' => 'done')));
    }
}
```

the first ajax call echo **{"response":"done"}** in chrome console,but second and other request echo **{"response":"not logged in"}**.
when I check session table in phpmyadmin,it will regenerate session id,with other user-agent

[image]

as you seen **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3** changed to **Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0) AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.0** in ajax request.but I use ubuntu with google chrome browser!!!.

Comment: I don't know how to set session name in CodeIgniter but try once `session_name()` function where you can.

Comment: what's `_remap` _function_ doing in a constructor? O_O

can functions be inside a constructor? _masaka_

Comment: Make sure the edit controller is doing a session_start().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also had the same problem with CodeIgniter sessions.

i switched to native sessions:
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dariusz-Debowczyk's-Session-Class

i never really understood the reasoning behind implementing yet another session mechanism (i am not talking about the CI_Session) when php has a good one already. :)